# Custom Validation for phone numbers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, customvalidator

I am having some trouble with custom validation in rails. I want to validate that only numbers are being put into the field where they choose dial in the drop down list.

my code thus far

```
validate :validate_numericality_of_dial_arg

def validate_numericality_of_dial_arg
    if action_type == "dial"
      return action_dst =~ /^\d+$/
    else
      errors.add(:base, "must be numbers")
    end
end
```

right now I am getting the error to pop up saying must be numbers even if the user enters numbers

Comment: Could run `puts "~#{action_dst}~"` inside the method and paste the output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to insist on using a custom validator, you can always use some rails magic:

```
## app/model.rb
validates :action_dst, numericality: true, if: -> {action_type == "dial" }
```